# How to access my local [WAMP] webserver from outside the LAN?

Tags: webserver, ip-address, wampserver

I am trying to access my local [WAMP] webserver from any remote devide. I am so far able to access it from a device inside the LAN, but fail to do so from outside it. As far as i know, port forwarding is how we achieve this. But currently unable to do that correctly.

Present error when trying to connect :
[image]

Some of the articles which i have followed so far are:

- [general-port-forwarding-guide](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/general-port-forwarding-guide/)
- [how-can-i-access-my-server-from-outside-of-my-lan](https://superuser.com/questions/899865/how-can-i-access-my-server-from-outside-of-my-lan)
- [how-to-expose-a-local-development-server-to-the-internet](https://medium.com/botfuel/how-to-expose-a-local-development-server-to-the-internet-c31532d741cc)

The main steps which i follow are as follows:

1. Make sure server is accessible inside LAN.
2. Open router's port forwarding settings and port forward the set static ip address (in step 1). Set port 80 and 8080 for communicating.
3. Access the server via my public ip (can check public ip and if forwarded port is accessible from [here](https://www.portchecktool.com))

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary solution for testing purposes only with 8 hour server connection duration time limit (and a limited no. of server connections):
[access_local_server_remotely_for-Development-And-Testing-Only](https://ngrok.com) and [here](https://youtu.be/765cxF_N98s) is a video guide about how to use it.